# Does "wie" mean "as" in German or does it mean "how"?

Tags: german-to-english

When I write "wie" by itself on google translator, it comes up as "as" but when I used it in a sentence, it comes up as "how". Are both right? And if so, could you give me an example when I could use "wie" as in "as".

Comment: Google translate is not useful as a dictionary. Try this one: https://www.dict.cc/?s=wie

Comment: You may also use a traditional (printed) dictionary.

Comment: In the question: Wie heißen Sie? - the translation is "What is your name?" - so does "wie" also mean "what" at times?

Answer (score 5):

Just as you've already guessed, *wie* can both mean *how* (if used as a question word) and *as* (if used in a comparison).

## Question Word ("how")

> Wie groß sind deine Schuhe?
>
> How big are your shoes?

## Comparison of equal values ("as")

> Meine Schuhe sind genauso groß wie deine.
>
> My shoes are as big as yours.

## Comparison of unequal values ("than")

This might be an additional distraction for you, so if the following confuses you, just ignore it. There is also one regional specialty: In southern Germany, *wie* is also used as a comparative of unequal things, which translates into English as *than*:

So, in Baden-Württemberg, for instance, the following sentence is fine:

> Meine Schuhe sind größer wie deine.
>
> My shoes are bigger than yours.

while in written ("standard") German, the same sentence would need to be

> Meine Schuhe sind größer als deine.

---

Just a side note on the scope of this site: This site is not meant to replace a dictionary. We would like you to consult a dictionary before asking here. (Have a look here: [How do I ask good, on-topic questions about meaning, translations, or differences?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-about-meaning-translations-or-difference)) As infinitezero already pointed out in a comment, google translate is not a good source for translations. There are quite a few better dictionaries online, for instance dict.cc or leo.org

Comment: +1 really good answer. But it's important that in "standard" German, replacing "als" with "wie" for unequal values is wrong and may even annoy some people a lot. (Trust me, as a Swabian I know that struggle)

Comment: @miep OK, I changed wording a bit to underline that it's a must to use _als_ in standard German.

Answer (score 0):

Die Frage ist so schwierig **wie** eine Googlesuche, oder **wie** soll ich sie verstehen?

Das Wort wie kann also, je nach Kontext, so oder so benutzt werden.

> Wie spät ist es?
>
> So spät wie eben, nur etwas später.

Comment: I think, English questions should be answered in English. Besides that, I think we should be nicer to new members to the site and show a more helping attitude. Due to the latter, I give -1 here.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach   Da bin ich keiner festen Meinung. Im parallelen Französisch-Forum zum Beispiel lese ich lieber Antworten auf Französisch, denn ich besuche das Forum ja, um meine Französisch-Kenntnisse zu verbessern. Da finde ich englische Antworten regelrecht ärgerlich, und zwar auch, wenn ich gezwungen bin, englisch zu fragen, da ich nicht genug Französisch kann, eine ordentliche Frage mit vernünftigem Zeitaufwand zu formulieren.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Das war nicht der Grund für den Downvote. Dennoch scheint es mir klar, dass jemand, der nicht genug deutsch kann, um auf deutsch zu fragen, mit einer Antwort auf Deutsch vielleicht nicht viel anfangen kann. Aber es gibt eine Meta-Diskussion dazu.